# Blazor Server-side or ASP.NET Core Razor Pages for SaaS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, saas

I'm building a SaaS application and I am quite comfortable with both Blazor server-side and ASP.NET Core Razor Pages.

The app will be obviously be multi-tenant and database per tenant. The total of concurrent users might be high 100's to low 1000's.

Which framework is suited better for such a SaaS app? Are there any advantages or disadvantages to choosing one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend 2 frameworks for multi-tenancy.

1. [OrchardCore](https://orchardcore.net/)
2. [ABP.io](https://abp.io/)

Below are my opinions:

**Multi-Tenancy:**

OrchardCore gives you many features for free for multi-tenancy unlike abp.io which provides a basic one and if you want more features, you need to buy.

**Blazor-Support:**

Abp.io has both blazor wasm and server support. Additionally, you can also use asp mvc and angular. With OrchardCore you can create asp mvc modules but supports only blazor wasm.

**Database Provider:**

OrchardCore uses primarily uses YesSQL and it is possible to use entity framework but not for CMS. If you want to use entity framework or mongodb, abp.io is your option.

**CMS support:**

OrchardCore has a superior CMS support. You can use liquid or razor for templating. Many features are already available and you can develop tenant sites as well with theme support and more. I recommend OrchardCore if you strongly favour CMS.

**Conclusion:**

For me I prefer ABP.io because it is modern, supports blazor and other UI frameworks. You get to choose the type of project you want. The downside is that many features are available as premium. Which is the reason why my company uses OrchardCore than ABP.io because many features are already included in OrchardCore. But I think ABP.io should be a better option and to improve as a developer that is why I started to learn it in my free time.

**ABP.io project option selection**
[image]